# UITableViewCell with nested UICollectionView showing duplicate data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view where each cell contains a collection view. Each collection view has a horizontal slideshow of images. Each table view cell is configured with a view model, which contains an array of imageURLs for the nested collection view to use as a data source. All works well until I need to load my second page of data. Once I load my second page of data into the table view, the second page items seem to be duplicates of the items on the first page. But it's weird because I also have a page control under this collection view that's configured with the count of the imageURLs array, and the number of pages is correct. Just the images themselves are duplicating the first page.

Here is the cellForRow on the table view:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DataTableViewCell.id, for: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.configureWith(viewModel.getViewModelAt(indexPath.row))
  
    return cell
  }
```

Here is the cellForItem on the nested collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CensoredDataCollectionViewCell.id, for: indexPath) as! CensoredDataCollectionViewCell
      cell.setRemoteImage(with: viewModel.photoGalleryURLStrings[0])
      
      return cell
    }
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ImageCollectionViewCell.id, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    let imageURLString = viewModel.photoGalleryURLStrings[indexPath.row - 1]
    cell.setRemoteImage(with: imageURLString)

    return cell
  }
```

The `setRemoteImage` method just sets the cell's image view from an image on the server. The `indexPath.row - 1` is because the collection view has an extra cell at the beginning.

Here is the code in the view controller that makes a new network call when reaching the bottom:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == viewModel.dataCount - 1 {
      tableViewFooterLoadingWheel.startAnimating()
      viewModel.downloadData { [weak self] moreData in

        if moreData {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self?.tableViewFooterLoadingWheel.stopAnimating()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the success case of the network call where new items are appended to the data source:

```
case .success(let result):
  strongSelf.data.append(contentsOf: result.results)
        
  if let next = result.next {
    strongSelf.dataURL = next
  } else {
    strongSelf.dataURL = nil
  }
 
  completion(true)
```

For testing, the initial network call will give me 5 items for my table view. The first 2 items both only have one image for their nested collection view. Once I've loaded my second page, which for testing purposes only has 2 items, these two items have the same images as my first two on page 1. But as mentioned the number of page control pages maps to the correct number of image URL's. So somewhere the count of images is completely correct. Just not the actual image.

Apologies if some of this code is not necessary. Please do not recommend I reset content in prepareForReuse() unless that's all I can do as Apple says to not do this. Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Edited to include configureWith() function:

```
func configureWith(_ viewModel: dataViewModel) {
  self.dataViewModel = viewModel
  
  loadingWheel.startAnimating()
  avatarImageView.loadImageFromURL(dataViewModel.avatarImageURLString) { [weak self] in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self?.loadingWheel.stopAnimating()
    }
  }
  statusLabel.text = dataViewModel.status
  createdAtLabel.text = dataViewModel.created
  photoGalleryPageControl.numberOfPages = dataViewModel.photoGalleryURLStrings.count
  likesCountLabel.text = "\(dataViewModel.likeCount)"
  
  likesButton.isSelected = dataViewModel.isLiked

  commentsCountLabel.text = dataViewModel.commentCount
}
```

Comment: When debugging this, is `viewModel.downloadData` giving you your expected data? Is `viewModel.getViewModelAt(indexPath.row)` giving you what you expect? Is `viewModel.photoGalleryURLStrings[indexPath.row - 1]` giving you what you expect?

Comment: It seems that all the information is correct yes. Just not the display. The first cell in every collection view has a black box over it with opacity, and once you slide past it you see the first image. Which the URL is correct for when printed out. But now if I scroll all the way to the bottom of table the last cell is already scrolled to the first item, which is the same image as the first, but no URL is loaded (which it should be different too) because the table view thinks I already scrolled inside this cell. So it's like the table view thinks indexPath 0 is also indexPath 6 for example.

Comment: Show us your `configureWith(...)` func in your table view cell. Or, better, show us your whole `DataTableViewCell` class.

Comment: I would expect you need to call `.reloadData()` to reload the collection view embedded in your table view cell?

Comment: That actually solved one part of the problem. Thanks. Now I can see the correct images. The issue where the first cell when scrolled causes the last one on page 2 to already be scrolled is still present though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table view cells are **reused** ...

As you've seen, you need to call `.reloadData()` on the embedded collection view when you set new data for the cell.

For the second issue - the embedded collection view is not "re-created" when the cell is reused. That means its scroll position (its content offset) does not change.

If you want the collection view to start at the first cell ***every time a row is scrolled into view***, you need to also call:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
```

when the cell is configured / shown.

If you want the collection view's scroll position to remain the same as you scroll the table, i.e.:

- table row 0, scroll horizontal collection view to cell 8
- scroll down the table view
- scroll the table view back up to the top, and have its collection view still scrolled to cell 8

then you'll need to track the collection view's content offset in your table view controller for each row.